# Running macros in Access 2016 from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, macros, office365, ms-access-2016

I have a desktop application written in VB.net that runs a macro in an access. Recently we upgraded from office 2010 to office 365. Now when i run this application i get this error :

Exception that comes up
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgUhV.png)

> Could not load  file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Acces.Dao,Version =15.0.0.0...' or one of its dependencies'

Below is the code that causes the exception:

```
If _accessApp Is Nothing Then
        _accessApp = New Application

    End If


    Try
        If JobFolderPath.Length <= 0 Or JobFolderPath Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If _accessApp.CurrentDb() Is Nothing Then

            _accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(JobFolderPath & "somedb.mdb", False)
            _accessApp.Run("SomeProcess")

        Else
            _accessApp.Run("SomeProcess")
        End If
        _accessApp.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone)

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        _accessApp = Nothing
    End Try
```

I even included teh Interop.Access.Dao verion 15 dll in the references for the project. Not sure if this way of running macros is obsolete in access 16. If so, what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error also says "or one of its dependencies", install the interop from the link below.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/15.0.4795.1000

Click on "Manual Download on the right ...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but a macro can be run without Access references with [late binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164798):

```
Dim accObj = GetObject(JobFolderPath & "somedb.mdb")    ' opens the file if not already open
accObj.Application.Run("SomeProcess")            ' the .Application part might not be needed
accObj.Application.Quit(2)                                 ' AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone = 2
```

or [command line switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Access) (also not tested):

```
Process.Start(JobFolderPath & "somedb.mdb" "/x SomeProcess")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to fix it by installing 'microsoft office 16.0 access database engine'(32 bit version) and adding the required dlls as COM references instead of normal dll references.